# Do universities know that you have re-applied

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

Do universities know that you are a re-applicant who applied to the same program last year? Do they keep that database? And if they do, does that hurt your chances? (Specific to universities in the US and the UK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do universities know that you are a re-applicant who applied to the
>   same program last year?

Yes, they do. Moreover, many universities directly ask are you a re-applicant in application forms.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly *some* will retain that information. It would be best to assume that they do unless you have information to the contrary.

I hope the reason for asking is not "Can I be dishonest in re-applying?". Such would be a mistake as is any sort of dishonesty in an application.

Of course, in reapplying you have another year of history. If you have done something interesting with that year be sure to mention it. Also address the quality of your personal and goals statement in a new application. If you were given a reason for refusal previously, make sure you address that.

Comment: The idea behind asking this is that whether it reflects negatively on my application as I'm a re-applicant or not.